# Specify exactly where content goes even when screen size changes

Tags: css

I'm trying to specify content specifically somewhere on the page, How can i do this so that it'll always be in the exact same spot even when screen size changes?

jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/4pkgfgwh/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iGIFvH6.png" style="width:354px;height:228px;">
  <div class="display">
    <p> Here is some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.display {
  position:absolute; 
  TOP:45px; 
  LEFT:350px; 
}
```

Comment: Learn about flexbox

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning

Comment: @SLaks thanks ill check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on the parent container:

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iGIFvH6.png">
        <div class="display">
          <p> Here is some Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 354px;
  height: 228px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.display {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ompfnjc5/2/**

Comment: so you set the image container with the size of the image then i'm assuming that display is a child of the image container div having absolute position would keep it in the same spot?

Comment: @Eric inner elements with position absolute will be relative to parent containers with position relative. If no parent containers have position relative then it will be relative to the viewport.

Comment: ooh thanks for explaining and the link. really appreciate it!